# Adding a new unrecognized USB audio device

Tags: drivers, usb, sound

I have an old USB sound card here that lsusb shows as

```
07fd:0004 Mark of the Unicorn
```

It was not mentioned in https://usb-ids.gowdy.us/read/UD (I added it)

Is there any way I can see if device :0004 works with a generic driver?

arecord -l does not list the device.

Comment: Do you have the snd_usb_audio kernel module loaded? If not, does loading it cause your sound card to be detected?

Comment: I tried modprobe snd-usb-audio  it loads, tried options snd-usb-audio index=-2 vid=0x07fd pid=0x0004
in /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf too, I cant find any output, module shows up after alsa force-reload